# Searching an array with foreach loop and getting the index of element

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public char letter { get; set; }
    public double result { get; set; }
    public bool test { get; set; }
}
```

I declare an array:

```
MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[counter];
```

and fill it with some data.

I sort the array:

```
myArray = myArray.OrderBy(a => a.letter).ThenByDescending(a => a.result).ToArray();
```

Now let's say I have an `int i = 100` variable.

How would I iterate through this array fields and get the index of the first element that:

1. Has specified letter in letter field.
2. Has `test == false`
3. `result < i`

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
foreach(MyClass t in myArray.Where(a => a.letter == 'a')
{
     if(t.result < i && t.test == false) get index of that field
}
```

However, I'm unsure how to get the index of it. How do I do this?

Comment: First of all a char can not **contain** another char. ither the property is of type `string` or **contain** expression should be **equals**

Comment: If you need the index you should do a `for` instead of a `foreach` and do the filtering inside the `for` with an `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.FindIndex` should solve the problem for you:

```
int correctIndex = Array.FindIndex( myArray , item => item.letter == 'a' && item.result < i && !item.test );
```

The second parameter is functionally equivalent to how you would describe it in a `.Where()` clause.

Also, just like similar indexing functions, it returns `-1` if the element isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the overload of `Select` that provides an index, like this:

```
var res = myArray
    .Select((val, ind) => new {val, ind}))
    .Where(p => p.val.result < i && p.val.letter == 'a' && !p.val.test)
    .Select(p => p.ind);
```

The first `Select` pairs up `MyClass` objects, as `val`, with their index, as `ind`. Then the `Where` method expresses the three conditions, including the one that pairs `result` and `ind`. Finally, the last `Select` drops the `MyClass` object, because it is no longer needed.

Comment: From OP's question, I'm assuming that the `i` variable *isn't an index*, but just a preset filter value.

Comment: It is, if i would need to word it I'd say: find me the index of the first element in array that has letter a, test == false and result smaller than i.

Comment: @Januszoff I think you are right, this should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I see the guys already did a great job answering your question with better alternatives, but just in case you still want to know how to do it with for each, here is how

```
int counter = 5 ; // size of your array
int i = 100 ; // the limit to filter result by
int searchResult = -1; // The index of your result [If exists]
int index = 0; // index in the array

MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[counter]; // Define you array and fill it
myArray[0] = new MyClass {letter = 'f' ,result = 12.3 , test = false } ;
myArray[1] = new MyClass {letter = 'a' ,result = 102.3 , test = true} ;
myArray[2] = new MyClass {letter = 'a' ,result = 12.3 , test = false } ;
myArray[3] = new MyClass {letter = 'b' ,result = 88 , test = true } ;
myArray[4] = new MyClass { letter = 'q', result = 234, test = false };

myArray = myArray.OrderBy(a => a.letter).ThenByDescending(a => a.result).ToArray(); // Sort the array

foreach(MyClass t in myArray.Where(a => a.letter == 'a')) // The foreach part
{
    if (t.result < i && t.test == false)
    {
        searchResult = index;
        break;
    }
    index++;
}

// And finally write the resulting index [If the element was found]
```

- Please note : Of course the resulting index will be the index in the sorted array

Answer (score 0):

Without `foreach`:

```
var item = myArray.FirstOrDefault(e => e.letter == 'a' && e.result < i && e.test == false);
int index = Array.IndexOf(myArray, item);
```